# PHP exec, system or passthru all remove single or double quotes

Tags: php, linux, exec, quote

When ever I try to execute a command to the shell via php's exec/passthru/system functions it seems to remove quotes from the command.

```
$str_file = '1323988284_700.csv';
exec("/usr/bin/lftp -e 'set ftp:passive-mode true; set ftp:ssl-protect-data yes; put /web/files/{$str_file}; bye;' -u user,pass ftp://ftp.site.com/uploaddir/");
```

Here is the output from checking the process

```
ps faxxx | grep lftp
4486 ?        S      0:00  |       \_ /usr/bin/lftp -e set ftp:passive-mode true; set ftp:ssl-protect-data yes; put /web/files/1323988284_700.csv; bye; -u user,pass ftp://ftp.site.com/uploaddir/
```

As you can see it's showing the process running with out the single quotes. This causes lftp to error.

Now it just hangs untill i kill it, i believe this is because if i type what is shown in the process list into the command like, it will error and leave you at the lftp shell.

PHP Safemode is OFF

I have tried the following for the quote's

```
\'
\\'
\\\'
\\\\'
''
'''
''''
```

---

### UPDATE

---

I'd like to add that upon further testing.. if I create a shell script (run_ftp.sh) and run that via php it also removes the quotes from the run_ftp.sh.. so this makes me think its NOT php causing the issue.

SELinux is off.. Is there any other security measures that linux/bash has in place that could cause this?

Comment: Have you tried http://php.net/escapeshellarg ?

Comment: Yes i have, it fails as well. The quotes are removed and im left with \ where the quote should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`exec()`](http://php.net/exec) and [`system()`](http://php.net/system) commands in PHP are passed over the shell. The shell parses the commandline and removes the quotes. It however keeps the whole string as one parameter, and shovels it to the actual [`execve()`](http://www.google.com/search?q=execve%28%29) system call etc.

The application will receive your string that was in single quotes *as one parameter*. The `ps` tool however might just list them as is.

It might however be that the `lftp` tool does some parsing of its own (the `-e` flag sounds like that). In which case two levels of quotes might help:

```
exec("lftp -e '\'multiple; commands; for the lftp thingy\''");
```

Comment: There isn't a form in PHP that avoids shell processing? Shells are such fickle animal homes.

Comment: No, it has no user input at all.

Comment: @pst: Not in the core functions, but I believe [`pcntl_exec()`](http://php.net/pcntl_exec) maps to the real system call. (Different behaviour of course, replacing current process.)

Comment: I tried this just now and some how the quotes are still being stripped and im left with ... -e \multipule; commands\ ...

Comment: @Antivanity: Can't help with that. It's however not PHP that strips them away. Which `$_SERVER["SHELL"]` type is active on your server?

Comment: @Antivanity: Your problem certainly aren't the quotes. That works fine with bash.

Comment: @mario I know it't the quotes that are the issue. It works fine with bash if i run it manually and not through php. "ps faxxx" Shows the command with out quotes. If i run it manually and check "ps faxxx" the quotes are there like it should be..

Comment: @Antivanity: Add your command to a shell script then (that won't help if it's actually the lack of pseudo tty or something) or try the aforementioned `pcntl_exec` instead.

Comment: @mario I ended up setting it up under a cronjob, as it works that way. This isnt the most efficient way.. but it works. I tried pcntl_exec() with the same results as before. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @Antivanity: Just had a look at `/etc/lftp.conf`. It certainly uses a shell internally too, which might break quotes. So trying to override with another `SHELL=/bin/zsh lftp ...` not sure if that might help. But another probable alternative could be using `lftp -f script_file` methinks then.

Answer (score 1):

Has anybody read the lftp man page?

It says under "OPTIONS":

-e commands      executes given commands and doesn't exit

-c commands      executes the given commands and exits

So your lftp hangs because you are using -e instead of -c.

It has nothing to do with PHP or the shell stripping out the quotes. The shell always does this, it's how it works. The output from PS is not meant to be copy-and-paste-able.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using the PHP function [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php). It's more complex, but works fine to me.

```
$command = "lftp -u $USER,$PASSWORD -e 'get /tmp/backup-2012-08-15.zip; bye' sftp://$HOST";

$io = array();            
$p = proc_open($command,
           array(1 => array('pipe', 'w'),
                 2 => array('pipe', 'w')), $io);

/* Read output sent to stdout. */
while (!feof($io[1])) {
    echo "STDOUT: ".fgets($io[1]);
}
/* Read output sent to stderr. */
while (!feof($io[2])) {
    echo "STDERR: ".fgets($io[2]);
}

fclose($io[1]);
fclose($io[2]);
proc_close($p);
```

This code was inspired in [PHP SHELL](http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/) tool.
PDT: Sorry by my English

Answer (score 0):

There is a self-explaining [UNIX SHELL Quote Tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html), give it a try!

Comment: I'm not sure this helps, as the problem is with php. I can execute the command via command line just fine.

Answer (score 0):

1) Write the args to a `tmp` file (this preserves the single quotes).
2)`exec("/usr/bin/lftp<tmp");`